# In Swift, how to update a Text view on main thread from inside async Task enclosure

Tags: swift, asynchronous, text, task

Here's the goal. I want to run a long async task and have it periodically send messages to the UI that will show up just below a spinning wheel activity indicator. Right now, I do not care about the activity indicator. I just need the async task to send a message at various stages of it's progress, and display that message to the user as it comes in.

So I've looked at GCD solutions, observable objects, actors, delegates, etc. A lot of the offered solutions are quite old and don't work, or they are new enough, but so complicated I'm not understanding them, me being pretty new to Swift.

I did get one approach to work, but it is so cheesy it really has to be the wrong way to do this. I just created an extension to my main view so I could house the async function in a separate file (it's kind of big). So the string var I use in the UI is visible to the async task. But it only actually updates if I have a 'try await' happen. That must trigger something in the UI to refresh the string and redisplay the layout. But it just seems goofy. There must be a better way.

Anyway, here's my workaround. BTW, this is pretty much the entire project, devoted to just this one problem. I've stripped out all the failed alternatives I couldn't get to work. Also, please forgive the task sleep extension. I'd rather work in seconds than nanoseconds.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var progressmsg: String = ""
    @State var loadingViewShowing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Download Something") {
                loadingViewShowing = true
                Task {
                    print("try 1")
                    progressmsg = "doing first sleep task"
                    try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
                    
                    print("try 2")
                    await diggingEvenDeeper()
                    
                    print("try 3")
                    progressmsg = "doing third sleep task"
                    try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
                    loadingViewShowing = false
                }
            }
            if !loadingViewShowing {
                Text("Nothing Happening ...")
            } else {
                ProgressView().scaleEffect(1.0, anchor: .center)
                Text("\(progressmsg)").font(.title).fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
    
}

extension ContentView {
    
    func diggingEvenDeeper() async {
        //really long process, need a message on stages of progress

        print("trying to start")
        self.progressmsg = "doing second & really long sleep task"
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
}

extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {
    static func sleep(seconds: Double) async throws {
        let duration = UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000)
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
    }
}
```

Comment: A view model class conforming to `@ObservableObject` is a much better way than doing all the *controller* stuff in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this to work. Thank you @vadian for your suggestion. I took another look at @ObservableObject and noticed some details I'd missed before. Basically, by using @StateObject to keep an eye on my observable class (struct didn't work), it provided a stable place for my background thread to reference (if I'm saying that correctly).

I would also point out that in my actual project I was getting those purple error messages about how it's not allowed to update published items from a background thread, so I also had to wrap my progress messages in a DispatchQueue.main.async enclosure. Weird the tiny example program didn't complain. Oh well.

Anyway, here's the working solution:

```
import SwiftUI

class Progress: ObservableObject {
    @Published var message = "Doing something ..."
    @Published var value = 0.0
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var progress: Progress = Progress()
    
    //@State var progressmsg: String = ""
    @State var loadingViewShowing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Download Something") {
                loadingViewShowing = true
                Task {
                    print("try 1")
                    progress.message = "doing first sleep task"
                    try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
                    
                    print("try 2")
                    await diggingEvenDeeper(progress: progress)
                    
                    print("try 3")
                    progress.message = "doing third sleep task"
                    try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
                    loadingViewShowing = false
                }
            }
            if !loadingViewShowing {
                Text("Nothing Happening ...")
            } else {
                ProgressView().scaleEffect(1.0, anchor: .center)
                Text("\(progress.message)").font(.title).fontWeight(.semibold)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
    }
    
}

//extension ContentView {
    
func diggingEvenDeeper(progress: Progress) async {
        //really long process, need a message on stages of progress

    print("trying to start")
    progress.message = "doing second & really long sleep task"
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(seconds: 5)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
    
//}

extension Task where Success == Never, Failure == Never {
    static func sleep(seconds: Double) async throws {
        let duration = UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000)
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
    }
}
```